# Multiple path parameters are not working in node-rest-client

Tags: node.js, rest, express, node-rest-client

I'm using node-rest-client library on the portal side of my project to call my rest APIs.

I have the following registered Method on the portal side:

```
client.registerMethod("addFriendToUser", host + "/users/&{userId}/friends/${friendId}", "POST");
```

When I call it on the following way with two string parameters, only one of them will appear on the api-side:

```
var args = {
    path: {
        'userId':   '1',
        'friendId': '2'
    },
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": /* ... */
    }
};

client.methods.addFriendToUser(args, function(data, response) {
    // ...
});
```

On the API side I have the following endpoint:

```
// ...
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/users/:userId/friends/:friendId')
    .post(/* ... middleware to check the Auth token from the header */, function(req, res, next) {
        // ...
        // Debugging the request parameters
        console.log(req.params);
        // ...
    });
```

In this case I will see the following parameters in the `req.params`:

```
{
    userId: '&{userId}', 
    friendId: '1' 
}
```

It seems that my first parameter doesn't get forwarded to the endpoint. If I call the endpoint directly from POSTMAN it works fine. I also tried to switch the parameters but same result.

And I also checked the [source code on github](https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client/blob/master/lib/node-rest-client.js#L170) but cannot figure it out what could be the problem:

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a syntax error:

```
client.registerMethod("addFriendToUser", host + "/users/&{userId}/friends/${friendId}", "POST");
```

should be:

```
client.registerMethod("addFriendToUser", host + "/users/${userId}/friends/${friendId}", "POST");
```

Note the misplaced `&` where `$` is required